# What is the maximum desktop resolution in Windows

Tags: windows, resolution

I found in one of the blogs the following statement:

> Windows does have a hard limit on maximum resolution and overall pixel count. The maximum continuous windows desktop available is up to 32k horizontal pixels by up to 32k vertical pixels with an overall pixel limit of 128 million pixels. Which means that a 32k x 32k desktop is not actually possible.

Does anybody know if there is a kind of whitepaper or spec from Microsoft which describes that limits?

Comment: Your pretty much quoting it. The simple fact is there isn't hardware that exists that can push 32K x 32K but I am pretty sure 1,024,000 pixels is smaller then 1,028,000 pixels. Any whitepaper or released documentation would exist on Microsoft website.

Comment: You probably can't hit 32Kx32K on today's systems, but you should be able to hit 32Kx1K, for example, with a mere 16 monitors. The limitation means that you can't have a 48Kx1K desktop, for example, or a 1Kx48K desktop.

Comment: Ramhound: 128 million is 128,000,000, not 1,028,000, and 32,000 x 32,000 = 1,024,000,000, not 1,024,000... 128,000,000 is only an eighth of 1,024,000,000.

Comment: `one of the blogs` which blog is that? why don't show the link

Answer (score 1):

16k is the actual limit based on COTS available hardware, if you try and build a system beyond 16k in a single direction, the graphics driver will crash. So while it may be a nice theoretical 32k limit for the OS, there is no supporting hardware, therefore the actual limit is 16k x 16k.